# ASP.NET create excel pivot table

Tags: asp.net, excel

May I know if there has something can help to create excel pivot table for ASP.NET? Thanks.

I heard there is a Office Web Component. Is it free and can it make pivot table?
Since we have some complex Excel vba file, we would migrate it into pure web based generated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWC is deprecated. See [Office Web Components Lifecycle](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2009/06/30/office-web-components-lifecycle.aspx) which states the following:

> The most important thing to be aware of is that the Office Web Components technology has been deprecated. This means that only security fixes are being made to all versions of OWC, and no future versions of OWC will be produced. If you are using OWC, you should begin migrating to a new technology as soon as possible. For more information, see the blog post "Office Web Components Roadmap".

Use Excel services instead. See [Replacing OWC Reporting with Excel Services](http://blogs.office.com/2008/01/09/replacing-owc-reporting-with-excel-services/) for more information.

If you need to generate Excel files on the server side you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: How about NPOI? Is it good to use, or Open XML is better? Thanks